# How to run query from two tables with TABLE operator

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a task:

> You must define a collection type to hold the attributes of a line
>   item. Then create a table to hold the invoice data including
>   information about its line items. Do not define a separate table for
>   item. Simply include the attributes of any item that is referenced in
>   a line item directly within the line item itself.
>   You need to create
>   three invoices using the line item data shown below.

```
-------- --------- --------------- ------- ---------------------------- -------- --------- ----------
INV001 27-APR-18 CREDIT A000100 GREEN WIDGET 1 35.10 35.10 
                        A000200 BLUE WIDGET 3 35.10 105.30

INV002 27-APR-18 Due on Receipt A001000 WHITE WIDGET 5 35.10 175.50
                                A000800 ORANGE THREE-HANDLED WIDGET 8 45.99 367.92
                                A000200 BLUE WIDGET 6 35.10 210.60
                                A000700 YELLOW THREE-HANDLED WIDGET 2 43.25 86.50
                                A000400 ORANGE WIDGET 1 45.99 45.99
INV003 27-APR-18 Due on Receipt
```

**Display the line items for invoices:**

```
SELECT LI.*
FROM INVOICE I, TABLE(I.LINEITEMS) LI;
```

I created tables and filled them with data - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cacb503443bb162e03648370b3c53efd

But the request that I have to make does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need a way to link your line items to your invoices... Also you typically wouldn't store the total in the table but instead compute it when required.

Comment: What exactly does "But the request that I have to make does not work" mean?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner error - ```ORA-00904: "I"."LINEITEMS": invalid identifier```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh i know it, but the task it to run this query ```SELECT LI.*
FROM INVOICE I, TABLE(I.LINEITEMS) LI;```

Comment: This is strange, because there exists no collection or function called `I.LINEITEMS`. The alias `I` that you use for `INVOICE` in the query cannot be used in a `CROSS JOIN` reference in the same query (you'd have to use `CROSS APPLY` for this). Are you sure you are asked to use this exact query?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner here's the task -https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bsqmG69TpDFhZF3wJfyl4dfrtJuCo4zw/view

Comment: I have never worked with collections inside tables, but as far as I can tell the queries in tasks 1, 2, and 4 are invalid. (And how old is this document anyway to still suggest the 1980's join syntax?) As mentioned, you should be able to re-write those queries with `CROSS APPLY` (or rather `OUTER APPLY`, as you shall also show invoices without line items) to make them work.

Comment: `INVOICE` table must have a `LINEITEMS` / `ITEMS` mapping for the referencing to work out.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I added an answer, you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a translation of the answer I got from the guys on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123702/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-table) (I apologize in advance for any translation errors).

Nested table should be [declared as a column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/collection-data-types.html#GUID-2F2DD7A9-FC8B-4D79-9C19-4C15780A3ED5) in table `Invoice`. Table `LineItems` will be created automatically as specified in the clause `STORE AS`. There you go:

```sql
create or replace type LineItemT as object (
    ItemId varchar (50),
    Quantity int,
    Description varchar (50) ,
    UnitPrice decimal (10,5) ,
    LineTotal decimal (10,5)
    )
/    
create or replace type LineItemsТ as table of LineItemТ
/
create table Invoice (
    Invoice# varchar (50) not null,
    shipdate date,
    terms VARCHAR(50),
    LineItems LineItemsT 
)
nested table LineItems store as LineItems
/
```

Fill in the data and the query will work:

```sql
insert into Invoice values (
    'INV001', date'27-04-18', 'CREDIT', 
    LineItemsT (LineItemT ('A000100', 1, 'GREEN WIDGET', 35.10, 35.10),
                LineItemT ('A000200', 6, 'BLUE WIDGET',  35.10, 210.60)));

select Invoice# invNo, li.* 
from invoice i, table (i.lineitems) li;

INVNO      ITEMID       QUANTITY DESCRIPTION       UNITPRICE  LINETOTAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
INV001     A000100             1 GREEN WIDGET     35,1       35,1      
INV001     A000200             6 BLUE WIDGET      35,1       210,6
```

On [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c2a077bf9a817b1d8d63370aa937a49).

Comment: I am glad you found a solution. In my opinion the query is still invalid. A comma-separated join is a cross join (i.e. you can replace the comma with the word `CROSS JOIN`). In such cross join the order of tables does not matter (i.e. you should be able to switch what is before the comma and after the comma), but this doesn't work here. So, it seems Oracle is bending the SQL standard here a little in order to make this possible. A proper solution would involve `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY`. Please see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f4937d1a5566942a818ca280529a802